# How to remove drylok paint from copper pipe

Tags: basement, paint-removal, basement-insulation

What can I use to safely remove dried drylok paint from a copper pipe without damaging the pipe?

Can I use mineral spirits or acetone?  Maybe olive oil?

Comment: I don't think the drylok is a problem based on your last thread, but how much paint are we talking about here?

Comment: @SolarMike that was my previous question asking about its corrosive properties, but not about how to remove it.

Comment: @Matthew, the pipe is about half covered, a few brush strokes, 8" long section

Comment: @Matthew, I called the UGL technical support line and they said if I see discoloration, I should remove it.  The discoloration is only under the drylok.

Comment: Is the pipe straight? Can you take a photo of it? The reason is because I might suggest a different approach depending

Comment: While you were on the phone with UGL, did you ask _them_ about an appropriate solvent or mechanical method of paint removal?

Comment: @Matthew it's about 6" long coming out of the wall

Comment: @FreeMan they didn't have a suggestion other than their UGL Green product which I can't find in my area